# Create Transaction and Trigger on a field

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Please am new in vb.net and sql server, I have created a two tables in database called Service and Trans.

```
Create Table Service(
ServiceID int,
ServiceName varchar(30),
ServiceStartValue int
);

Create Table Trans(
EntryTS datetime,
EntryCounter int,
ServedTS datetime,
ServedCounter int,
Skipped int
);
```

I am trying to create a 'transaction and trigger' that will check and update ServedCounter based on the values in EntryCounter upon ServiceID which the update statement must not allow the ServedCounter > EntryCounter.

Comment: It is better to do this in the query and avoid trigger. Triggers are mostly for post-development additions and optional features.

Comment: the requirement is not clear. what's the value to insert into `ServerCounter`? how do you calculate it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the full requirement, but here's how you can prevent a update (or insert) from happening with a trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trans_upd_trg ON Trans AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--Don't allow the update
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE ServedCounter > EntryCounter)
    RAISERROR ('ServedCounter > EntryCounter', 16,  1 );
END
GO
```

Within the context of the trigger you have two logical tables, INSERTED, and DELETED.
These tables contain the old and new values. (deleted is empty for a insert operation)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Instead Of Trigger`

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trans_upd_trg
ON Trans
Instead OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      IF EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM   inserted
                 WHERE  ServedCounter > EntryCounter)
         AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM   deleted)
        UPDATE A
        SET    EntryTS = I.EntryTS,
               EntryCounter = I.EntryCounter,
               ServedTS = I.ServedTS,
               ServedCounter = I.ServedCounter,
               Skipped = I.Skipped
        FROM   Trans A
               JOIN inserted I
                 ON A.EntryTS = I.EntryTS
                    AND A.ServedTS = I.ServedTS
        WHERE  i.ServedCounter > i.EntryCounter
      ELSE
        INSERT INTO Trans
        SELECT *
        FROM   inserted
        WHERE  ServedCounter > EntryCounter
  END

GO
```